# Run command on Android phone from PC

Tags: android, windows

I am using tethering on an Andorid phone to share the internet connection to my PC.
Sometimes I need to get a new IP address, for that I switch to airplane mode, then disable it and I get a new IP. I am looking for a way to do this trick from my pc.
So I need to run a single command on my phone from my PC, and I have absolutely no idea on how to do it, and if i need to root my android device.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Using ADB (no root required)**

```
// Open Wifi settings screen
adb shell am start -a android.settings.WIRELESS_SETTINGS

// Call key down event
adb shell input keyevent 20

// Call key click event to turn off wifi
adb shell input keyevent 23

// Key click again to turn on wifi
adb shell input keyevent 23

// Get the ip address
adb shell ip route
```

### **Using SVC (root required)**

```
// Disable Wifi
adb shell su -c 'svc wifi disable'

// Enable Wifi
adb shell su -c 'svc wifi enable'

// Get the ip address
adb shell ip route
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need, thank you very much !